# c# as keyword reference assignment

Tags: c#

Just wondered if I have a variable constructed as follows

```
object a = new CustomClass;
CustomClass b = a as CustomClass;
```

and I then manipulate b by invoking b.DoWork

Do I need to assign b back to a  (a=b) or am I correct in thinking they both refer to the same reference / memory address

EDIT:

Thanks for the answers - It looks like there is no need to do teh assignment (a=b) as both point to the same object

Comment: I think there may be a typo in your code, the second line is trying saying "Try to make CustomClass "a" into a CustomClass, and assign it as a string."  It doesn't make sense as is, I'm afraid...  Did you mean string b = a as string; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are references to the same object (I'm assuming that by naming your class CustomClass you actually mean it's a class (reference type), not a struct, because if it would be a structure, you can't use `as` operator to cast it). Also, I assume you meant to write:

```
object a = new CustomClass();
CustomClass b = a as CustomClass;
```

in your code (notice `()` and you can't cast it to string).

Answer (score 2):

This will not compile, unless you can assign `CustomClass` to a string. You can't assign the return type of `as` to a `string` type unless a conversion exists.

From MSDN, the [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) keyword is equivalent to the following (apart from `expression` being evaluated only once):

```
expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null
```

So, it returns an object of the *type* - in this case `CustomClass`. Unless you can assign `CustomClass` to a `string`, this will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it depends if CustomClass is implemented as a reference type or a value type.

Have a look at [this reference](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) for more detail.